# Examples of topologies on R

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the basics of topology from munkres. I know the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined by open intervals $(a,b)$. However, I was unable to think of any other examples apart from the trivial and discrete topology. Are there any other nice topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ that can I appreciate equally well from real analysis perspective as in the case of open sets $(a,b)$?

For ex, I understand that the usual $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space, are there any non-metric topological spaces on the set of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Continue reading Munkres and you will find other topologies.

Comment: There are a gazillion topologies on any infinite set and very few of these will be metrizable. Interesting non-metric topologies specific to $\Bbb{R}$, are the [Sorgenfrey topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) and the [left and right order topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies).

Comment: Have a look at the classic book "Counterexamples in Topology".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. As far as I understand, the open sets were a  special class on collection of subsets on $\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering, if there is any other simple example that I can get, ie, another class of open sets on \mathbb{R}? Sorry sir, I was just curious about a new kind of topology. Because, the examples that I've gone through are some lever manipulation of how the open sets are defined and not something very different from open sets seen throughout analysis. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're familiar with the concept of a basis for a topological space. If so, then the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $(a,b]$ is neither trivial, discrete, or the usual metric topology. Similarly, using $[a,b)$ as generating sets gives another distinct and interesting topology.

Another topology on $\mathbb{R}$, which I think was used when I first learned topology as the first example of a nontrivial non-Hausdorff topology is to let all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite complement be open. (You can check it satisfies the definition.) This is actually a pretty weird topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember this example. The finite complement being open was a clever example.  But I couldn't get a grasp of it. Is there any other wierd example that you can think of? Thank you.